# Restricting VectorPlot3D to a specific region

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to visualize the vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cosh(t) & \sinh(t)\\
0 & \sinh(t) & \cosh(t)
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $t$ is a real number, when restricted to the upper sheet of the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$. Here are my two attempts:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y Cosh[t]+z Sinh[t], y Sinh[t]+z Cosh[t]}, 
            {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
            RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b, c}, a^2 + b^2 - c^1 == -1]]
```

and

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y Cosh[t]+z Sinh[t], y Sinh[t]+z Cosh[t]}, 
             {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
             RegionFunction -> ((#1^2+#2^2-#3^2==-1) &)]
```

These are both based off of examples I saw in the VectorPlot3D documentation, but they both return empty graphs. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

You need a region of dimension 3:

```
t = 1;
VectorPlot3D[{x, y Cosh[t] + z Sinh[t],  y Sinh[t] + z Cosh[t]},
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> (( #1^2 + #2^2 - #3^2 < -1) &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could try something more "manual" to capture the vectors on your region of interest only :

```
field[x_, y_, z_, t_] := {x, y Cosh[t] + z Sinh[t], y Sinh[t] + z Cosh[t]};
p = .2; 
t = Table[Arrow[{{r Sin@tet, r Cos@tet, z}, 
                 {r Sin@tet, r Cos@tet, z} + p field[r Sin@tet, r Cos@tet, z, 1]}] /. 
               r -> Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, 5, 1}, {tet, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/10}];

Show[ContourPlot3D[1 == x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5}, 
                   Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> {Orange, Opacity[.5], 
                                                   Specularity[White, 3]}], 
   Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], t}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could also use something like `RegionFunction -> (( -1 -.1#1^2 + #2^2 - #3^2 < -1 + .1) &)]`